Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline is Queued
While running pipeline in Optimizely CMS it is queued. And for 15 minutes it's not even starting for the Start up project. The error is not understandable and the pipeline is valid.

And as you can see i have only one pipeline. So how to proceed further.
The pipeline code for Build restore and moving the Optimizely CMS project to the DXP.
# Pipeline to deploy to Integration DXP environment using Azure App Service Deploy task
# -----------------------------

# Set the pipeline build number format
name: $(Build.DefinitionName)_$(SourceBranchName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
- name: solution
  value: '**/*.sln'
- name: buildConfiguration
  value: 'Release'
- name: workingDirectory
  value: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/'
- name: sourcePath
  value: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/SitePackageContent'
- name: artifact.Name
  value: "ADGM CMS DXP Package"
- name: archiveName
  value: 'ADGM_Migration.cms.app.$(Build.BuildId).nupkg'
# - group: Optimizely-common-vars

stages:
- stage: CI
  jobs:
  - job: CI
    displayName: 'Build & package'
    steps:    
    - script: dotnet restore ./ADGM_Migration.sln
      displayName: Restore
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
    
    - script: dotnet build ./ADGM_Migration.sln --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
      displayName: Build
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      
    - script: dotnet publish ./ADGM_Migration.Cms --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(sourcePath)
      displayName: PUBLISH ADGM_Migration CMS DXP Artifact
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: "Archive Files"
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(sourcePath)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(archiveName)'
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(archiveName)'
      artifact: $(artifact.Name)
      
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Upload package to DXP'
      env:
        # Map secret variable
        API_SECRET: $(ApiSecret)
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $env:PSModulePath = "C:\Modules\azurerm_6.13.1;" + $env:PSModulePath
          if (-not (Get-Module -Name EpiCloud -ListAvailable)) {
              Install-Module EpiCloud -Scope CurrentUser -Force
          }
          Connect-EpiCloud -ClientKey $(APIKEY) -ClientSecret $env:API_SECRET -ProjectId $(ProjectId)
          
          $packagePath = "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(archiveName)"
          
          $saslink = Get-EpiDeploymentPackageLocation
          Add-EpiDeploymentPackage -SasUrl $saslink -Path $packagePath

- stage: Integration 
  jobs:
    # Add a Deployment job. 
    # Artifacts are automatically downloaded in deployment jobs. To disable use -download: none
  - deployment: DeployApp
    displayName: 'Deploy to Integration'
    variables: 
      # Explicitly set the EnvironmentName variable in multi-stage YAML to ensure environment config transform is applied automatically
      Release.EnvironmentName: 'Integration'
    # Creates an environment if it doesn't exist

    environment: 'Integration'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: none

          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: 'Deploy to Integration'
            # env:
            #   API_SECRET: $(APISECRET)
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                if (-not (Get-Module -Name EpiCloud -ListAvailable)) {
                    Install-Module EpiCloud -Scope CurrentUser -Force
                }
                Connect-EpiCloud -ClientKey $(ApiKey) -ClientSecret $(APISECRET) -ProjectId $(PROJECTID)
                $packageName = "$(archiveName)"
                
                echo "Starting deployment using package $packageName" 
                $params = @{
                  DeploymentPackage = $packageName
                  TargetEnvironment = 'Integration'
                  UseMaintenancePage = $false
                  DirectDeploy = $true
                  Wait = $true
                }
                $deploy = Start-EpiDeployment @params
                
                echo "DeploymentId - $($deploy.id)" 
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=deploymentId;]$($deploy.id)"

The running response from the pipeline in yaml format.


Can you please provide more details? What do you see if you click on that pipeline run? Pipeline could be waiting for you to give access to something but we won't see that from here. Can you paste the YAML of the pipeline as well?

Let me update the question.

Let me update the question. @KonTheCat

Can you please add a screenshot of the screen before the one where you have the details of the Build & Package step?
This is a new Azure DevOps environment, into which you are deploying an established and known-good process? Some years ago it was the case that you would have to request the Microsoft-managed agents to be enabled, but I am not seeing that in the documentation. And IIRC it would be this step that shows the error for that. This may be a support issue.
Relevant doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Verify the availability and health of the agent pool being used by your pipeline. Ensure that agents are available and operational within the pool to handle incoming pipeline execution requests.

Per the Azure DevOps Status history, there's an active event on 3rd April which may impact uks region orgs. It's mitigated now, so please check if it works now.
